# Quill editor selects whole element and not just a part of the text

Tags: javascript, quill

I am working with the Quill editor and made it that it works with one toolbar for multiple Quill's. I now have a issue (see video) with the selection.

The problem is that if you want to edit the content quill selects the complete span or other element that the content is in. Also it is not possible to start at the end of the text.

this is my Quill init / config (I use the Quill api for all changes)

```
            let quill = new Quill(selector, {
                placeholder: "Enter text here...",
                modules: {
                    toolbar: false
                }
            });
```

**Video with the problem:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/211vzee04sioq4i/My%20Movie.mp4?dl=0

Thank you

Comment: can you show your config for quill and some code where you init it, thanks

Comment: @episch added the config :)